# When to use _e and __ for the translation?

Tags: theme-development, translation

What is difference between `_e()` and `__()` functions for the translation? In what cases `e()` and `__ ()`should be used?

Comment: For purposed of expanding, check [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/translating-your-theme--wp-25014).

Comment: Additionally see: [Codex: Translating Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) and [Codex: I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to `echo` the translated string, then you will be using `_e` and when you just want to have the translated string, then you will be using `__`.

**Example:**

```
_e('this is a message', 'twentyfourteen');
```

is same as

```
echo __('this is a message', 'twentyfourteen');
```

Comment: Does `_e()` *return* the translated string, or just echo in place? For example, would `$x = _e('1','2'); echo $x` echo the translated string twice? Would the first line run?

Comment: `__('this is a message', 'twentyfourteen');` gives the translated string. Then it's upto you how you want to use that result.