# Conflict with single and double quotes

Tags: images, translation

This might be a very silly question but I am losing my hair over this.. So basically, I have the following line of code"

```
        'Default'  => '<img src="' . THEMEROOT . '/admin/images/default.png" width="120" height="80" alt="<?php _e( 'Default', 'my_theme' ); ?>"/>',
```

The problem I am having is the alt text is printing like this:

```
<?php _e( 'Default', 'my_theme' ); ?>
```

instead of just the "Default" word.. It is a conflict between double and single quotes, but I can't figure out how to fix it. What am I doing wrong here?(please be gentle, I am a new in these things :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sometimes easier to work with `sprintf()`:

```
 'Default'  => sprintf( 
     '<img src="%s/admin/images/default.png" 
           width="120" 
           height="80" 
           alt="%s" 
       />',
      get_template_directory(),
      esc_attr__( 'Default', 'my_theme' )
);
```

where we use the [`esc_attr__()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr_2) to return a translated value that's safe to be used in an attribute, but I'm not sure what your `THEMEROOT` contains, so I just replaced it with [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it completely wrong and your problem isn't just in quotes. It should be like this:

```
'Default'  => '<img src="' . THEMEROOT . '/admin/images/default.png" width="120" height="80" alt="' . __( 'Default', 'my_theme' ) . '"/>',
```

Function docs `__( $text, $domain )` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2

For reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836675/what-is-the-difference-between-the-wordpress-e-and-functions-ho
- [When to use _e and __ for the translation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147633/when-to-use-e-and-for-the-translation)